# Multiple Php pages Do Not load at the same time in one Browser

Tags: php

For some reason, I found there is a problem when viewing my website, that only one php page can be loaded at a time in the browser. 
For example, if I open "PageA.php" then open "PageB.php", "PageB.php" does not return any result (shows loading..) until "PageA.php" finishes loading.

I am using Apache Httpd on CentOS. Can someone help me please?

Thanks!!

Comment: did you tested another page, you can test with simple html page and check if same behavior occurs.

Comment: Guess we need way more insight about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using file-based PHP sessions, which by default lock the session file when a particular script instance is using the session. This will cause any other hits on scripts that use the same session to be locked out until the first script is completed.

If you need to have long-running scripts and/or allow parallel usage of the pages, you'll have to explicitly release the session lock in the scripts with `session_write_close()`.

If you do so, `$_SESSION` will still be available for read/writing, but will no longer auto-save changes when the scripts exits. You can, however, do another `session_start()` later (assuming no output has been performed) to "resume" the session and enable the auto-save behavior again.